# Find amount of trials needed to generating the same number twice with 0.8 probaility

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a function that generates a 32-bit long number of 0 and 1 (ie. {0, 1}^32). How many numbers would I have to generate such that at least two of them are identical with a probability greater than 0.8?

I'm having trouble understanding how to solve this problem. I know that there are 2^32 possible numbers. And the chance of getting the same number twice would be (1/2^32 )^2 or 1/2^64. But this doesn't seem to account for getting ANY number twice or the chance being greater than 0.8.

Could anyone give an explanation?

Comment: Look up the [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Comment: So in my case would I simply need to set it up like:

1 - ((2^32)/(2^32 - n)) / (2^32)^n

Where n is the amount of numbers generated. Would I then find the n that would make the equation > 0.8?